# Why does Peoplesoft Component Interface error out when pulling records from Dynamic Views?

Tags: peoplesoft

Can Peoplesoft Component Interface pull records from Dynamic Views? I keep getting the error invalid value -- press the prompt button or hyperlink for a list of valid values (15,11) when running CI through the app engine but when I use Test CI it works perfectly. I tried checking if the App engine is getting the values that would be inserted and it does. But the process cannot be completed because it says invalid value. The prompt uses a dynamic views.

Answer (score 0):

Is the user running the CI the same running the Test CI? Dynamic views are usually related to the user executing, so if your user has security to see data it will return values, otherwise no values will be returned, and you will see this error.
Adjust the security (or whatever is behind the dynamic view) to accommodate that.
Also, a SQL trace can help you troubleshoot this.